# Standard models of N and R: An Alice/Bob approach

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic, model-theory, nonstandard-analysis, sociology-of-math

This is a question about a comment in a recent publication by Roman
Kossak.  Kossak wrote:

> "Nonstandardness in set theory has a different nature.  In
> arithmetic, there is one intended object of study - the standard
> model.  There is no intended model in set theory.  Set-theorists talk
> about universes of sets, but what happens in those universes very much
> depends on the axioms that they satisfy, and there are many axiomatic
> systems to choose from.  There is no standard model of set theory, but
> still there is a notion of nonstandardness."
>
> [Model Theory of Nonstandard Structures with Applications](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-3-030-19071-2_71-1)

The point seems to be as follows.  First, the purported base model $\mathbb N$
seems to please everybody, and therefore deserves the name "the
standard model".  Meanwhile, the corresponding model of $\mathbb R$ given by
Goedel's computable reals does not please everybody because $V=L$ leads
to consequences that are considered too strong.  The point is not so much models of ZFC as models of $\mathcal P(\mathbb N)$ namely $\mathbb R$, where there is already a dispute with regard to the "minimal model". For example, if $V=L$ then $\mathcal P(\mathbb N)$ will satisfy CH, but other models will not.

Alice could argue regarding $\mathbb N$ that it has the special property that,
under any ZFC-like foundational system, $\mathbb N$ is the least model of the
Peano axioms.  Bob would respond that Goedel's constructible reals are
the least model of $\mathbb R$ in a similar sense to $\mathbb N$ being the minimal model
of PA.

Alice could argue that $\mathbb N$ is routinely identified with a rather subtle
thing that we may call the physical model of PA (counting pebbles,
etc.) and practical computation.

Bob would ask, as far as counting pebbles and practical computation
are concerned, $\mathbb N$ is "routinely identified" by whom exactly?  It is
perhaps the metalanguage integers that can be related to
pebble-counting etc.  However, the metalanguage integers form a
sorites-like subcollection that cannot be assumed to satisfy PA (of
course it would be different for formal computation).  The point was
argued in detail in a 2017 publication in Real Analysis Exchange
[https://u.cs.biu.ac.il/~katzmik/infinitesimals.html#17f](https://u.cs.biu.ac.il/%7Ekatzmik/infinitesimals.html#17f) Furthermore,
where would one look for a "physical model of PA" ?

Alice could argue that positing a minimal $\mathbb N$ appeals to the broader
mathematical public.

Bob would retort that Platonist notions may be appealing to such a
public, but are they are justified?

Alice could argue that, by Goedel, ZFC does *not* prove the
consistency of any model of ZFC; thus to get a model of ZFC, we would
need to argue in a suitable stronger theory.

Bob would counter by noting that Goedel incompleteness applies to
models of PA, as well.

Alice could argue that identifying a model $M$ of ZFC with any
assemblage of things bearing any form of physical existence is well
beyond any human vision of the world of things.

Bob would retort that, while $M$ is beyond any form of physical
existence, both $\mathbb N$ and $\mathbb R$ are embedded in such an $M$, so it may be hard
to argue for a difference between $\mathbb N$ and $\mathbb R$ based on the nature of $M$.
While it seems incontestable that such an $M$ can't be endowed with "any
form of physical existence", couldn't one argue the same for $\mathbb N$ and $\mathbb R$?

Such an analysis tends to confirm the following conclusions reached by
Rittberg:

> (1) the metaphysical views of mathematicians can shape what counts as
> relevant research; (2) mathematical results can shape the metaphysical
> beliefs of mathematicians; (3) metaphysical thought and mathematical
> activity develop in tandem in mathematical practices.
>
> [Mathematical Practices Can Be Metaphysically Laden](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-3-030-19071-2_22-1)

In conclusion, one could formulate the following query concerning
Kossak's view on the difference between standard models for $\mathbb N$ and $\mathbb R$.
Some people also find the so-called standard $\mathbb N$ displeasing, because it
does not reflect the historical record of mathematicians from Leibniz
to Cauchy who worked with infinite (in technical modern terminology,
unlimited) integers.  From this point of view, Edward Nelson's $\mathbb N$
(incorporating a distinction between standard and nonstandard integer,
the latter being unlimited) would be more satisfying.

Could one then argue that there is little difference between $\mathbb N$ and $\mathbb R$ on
account of the question of the existence of a standard/intended model?

**Note**.  In response to a *comment* below the *question* to the effect
that "standard means that the model is well-founded", note that
Nelson's $\mathbb N$ (incorporating the standard/nonstandard distinction, as
mentioned above) is well-founded in precisely the same technical sense
as in ZFC.  Another *comment* claimed that Kossak "is just making a
sociological observation.  People agree that the minimal model of
first-order PA deserves to be called the standard model of the natural
numbers".  My question concerns the meaning the definite article
before "standard model", as per above.

Comment: I don't think "the corresponding model of R given by Goedel's computable reals does not please everybody because V=L leads to consequences that are considered too strong" is quite right. I think set theorists don't like V=L because they like the richness of all the possible different models of set theory. It would be like saying "group theorists think assuming all groups are abelian leads to consequences that are too strong" - no, they just think non-abelian groups are interesting!

Comment: @SamHopkins, thanks for your correction.  Since I am not a set-theorist by training, any input of this sort is appreciated.  As would be an *answer* :-)

Comment: @SamHopkins I think many set theorists think there is an intended model of the ZFC axioms, or at least of the axioms of second-order arithmetic. Many of them reject $V = L$ on philosophical grounds other than the desire to consider many different models of the axioms. So the situation for these set theorists is different from the group theorists, who have nothing like an intended model for the group axioms.

Comment: @GabeGoldberg, Thanks for your comment.  With regard to the "intended model": Do you agree with my reading of Kossak's passage that Kossak himself does not "think there is an intended model of the ZFC axioms" ?  Of course, the term "intended model" is sometimes used in a relative sense (namely that some models are nonstandard relative to the intended one); but I take it that this not what you are talking about.

Comment: To the "closing" voters: I am trying to understand what Kossak meant by his published comment (as quoted in my *question*).  This is not opinion-based but rather a request for clarification/information.

Comment: I personally don’t see grounds to claim that the axioms of ZFC (or KP, etc.) couldn’t ever be ascribed physical meaning by human minds; it certainly hasn’t been done convincingly to my knowledge yet, but I don’t see why it should be impossible.

Comment: @AlecRhea, Roman Kossak seems to see a difference between N and R on this account; that's what I would like to understand.

Comment: @MikhailKatz Yes, I agree that this is what he means.

Comment: @MikhailKatz Your use of R is confusing. Kossak is talking about N and V, not N and R. In any case, I think that when Kossak says that there is no intended model of set theory, he's just making a sociological observation. People agree that the minimal model of first-order PA deserves to be called "the standard model of the natural numbers." People don't agree that the minimal (transitive) model of ZFC, or any other specific model of ZFC, deserves to be called "the standard model of set theory." I don't think there's anything deeper than that going on.

Comment: @AlecRhea Frankly I'm also skeptical that there's actually a reasonable notion of a physical model of PA. Between the big bang, the cosmological horizon, the heat death of the universe, and the Bekenstein bound, there's really only a finite amount of room for accessible physical data.

Comment: @JamesHanson The Feynman path integral, one of the most reliable (if not the best) predictive tool used by particle physicists at CERN etc., essentially weights possible realities by the likelihood of their physical constants and laws of physics, performs a sum over all possible realities, and arrives at a prediction of what will happen in our reality as the result of this summing process. In light of this (and other developments in cosmological physics etc.), I find arguments about how ‘our reality is finite’ specious; there may be an infinity of possible realities.

Comment: @AlecRhea All I can say is that in my time in theoretical physics, there was definitely a broad suspicion towards claims of actual physical infinity. So I can at least anecdotally say that *physicists themselves* do not find arguments like mine specious at all.

Comment: In set theory, "standard" means that the model is well-founded. This agrees with arithmetic. The difference is that there is only one well-founded model of arithmetic whereas there may be many well-founded models of a set theory. The idea of minimal models is a distraction.

Comment: @JamesHanson Yes, during my time working in the field almost all the people I knew would agree with you; I personally see analogies with the situation in mathematics circa 1800-1900 concerning whether infinities/infinitesimals actually existed in mathematics, and we see how that’s ended up — I think [Schopenhauer called it](https://www.brainyquote.com/quotes/arthur_schopenhauer_103608) on this one, and we’re approaching the end of stage one with modern theoretical physics.

Comment: @Timothy , You made two separate points in your *comment*.  First, you
claimed that Kossak is "just making a sociological observation."  If
this were the case, he would have used clauses such as "it is
customarily assumed that" or something of that sort.  Instead, he
writes categorically "The set of natural numbers N with addition and
multiplication is called the standard model of arithmetic" and "There
is no intended model in set theory" - period.  Whatever the merits of
such a position, it appears that he is *not* merely making a
sociological point that "people agree that, etc."

Comment: @Timothy , Second, as far as N and V versus N and R, I skipped a few
steps here.  Universes that are "fatter" than Goedel's V=L can exhibit
the discrepancy already at the level of P(N) (so that, for example,
Goedel's universe satisfies CH but "fatter" universes won't).  The
question at that level is equvalent to the question about R,
obviously.

Comment: @François, you wrote: "there is only one well-founded model of
arithmetic" but note that Ed Nelson's N in IST (incorporating the
distinction between standard and unlimited integers) is well-founded
in precisely the same technical sense as in ZFC.  Therefore the idea
of minimal models is not necessarily a "distraction."

Comment: @MikhailKatz "Called" and "intended" are sociological words, with no formal mathematical definition.

Comment: @Timothy , "intended model" is another term for "standard model".  The issue here is the claim of its existence, as contrasted with the situation for R (or V).

Comment: @MikhailKatz What I mean is that "there is no intended model of set theory" and "there is no standard model of set theory" are not theorems. They're sociological claims.

Comment: @Timothy , even as per your "sociological" claim, one can still ask where such a consensus (existence for N, nonexistence for R) comes from, and its apparently universal nature implied by the categorical tone of the comments found on page 2 of the paper (the same mentality is presumably behind the three closing votes on this *question*).  What I am asking is what Kossak meant.

Comment: @MikhailKatz That is a fair question, but I think it is too "soft" for MO. (Asking for clarification about what Kossak meant is fine for MO, I think.)

Comment: Your Real Analysis Exchange link does not load for me.  What is the author and title of the publication? \\ Also, [re](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/457042/standard-models-of-n-and-r-an-alice-bob-approach#comment1183773_457042), surely the only person who could answer what Kossak meant is Kossak?  We might discuss here what we think was meant, but that would be no more authoritative an interpretation than what you think was meant.

Comment: @LSpice, 17f. Fletcher, P.; Hrbacek, K.; Kanovei, V.; Katz, M.; Lobry, C.; Sanders, S. "Approaches to analysis with infinitesimals following Robinson, Nelson, and others." Real Analysis Exchange 42 (2017), no. 2, 193-252. https://arxiv.org/abs/1703.00425, https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=3721800  The DOI link doesn't for the article does not seem to work but see [here](https://u.math.biu.ac.il/~katzmik/17f.pdf)

Comment: [Re](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/457042/standard-models-of-n-and-r-an-alice-bob-approach#comment1184752_457042), thank you!  The DOI to [10.14321/realanalexch.42.2.0193](https://doi.org/10.14321/realanalexch.42.2.0193) works for me (and re-directs to https://www.jstor.org/stable/10.14321/realanalexch.42.2.0193), but, anyway, it's now clear what was meant.  I apologise that I also edited my [comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/457042/standard-models-of-n-and-r-an-alice-bob-approach#comment1184751_457042) while you were replying to it.

Comment: @LSpice, I am glad to get a variety of opinions concerning the question.  Note that Chow wrote above that "clarification about what Kossak meant is fine for MO" (I assume what he meant was that, Kossak being a professional logician, his views are likely typical of logicians and therefore other professional logicians may be able to speak competently here; but I am not sure; Chow similarly can only speak for himself :-)

Comment: I have the feeling this is yet another "question" whose whole point is to advertise OPs position and publications.

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker, the *question* concerns the meaning of Kossak's comment about standard models.

Comment: This is an interesting musing, but like @MichaelGreinecker and others, I don’t see an answerable MO-suitable question here.  The only grammatical question I can find in it is “Could one then argue that there is little difference between N and R on account of the question of the existence of a standard/intended model?” — which is both vague and trivially a “yes”, since you’ve just used 700 words presenting such arguments here; so presumably what you actually mean by this is “What do you all think of these arguments?” — but that is extremely open-ended and subjective.

Comment: @Peter, you seem to be trying to deny this, but there is a substantive issue here, that Chow and Dorais tried to address in the *comments* - and in rather different ways.  Since you seem to be a professional logician, why don't you try to post an *answer* instead?

Comment: @MikhailKatz: I quite agree the issue here is interesting and substantive, I’m not denying that in the least — but I also think it’s massively open-ended and subjective, which tends to be a bad fit for MO, and is explicitly against the site guidelines.  This could be a great blog post, or discussion-starter on a mailing list or forum-style site.  But MO works best for answerable questions, not discussions.

Comment: The question is not against site guidelines.  I would appreciate if this harassment could stop.  There was an attempt to close the *question*, which failed.  Enough!

Comment: Dear @MikhailKatz: I’m really sorry if my earlier comments came across as harrassing; I didn’t mean to go beyond collegial disagreement.  I find what you’ve written here interesting and thought-provoking, and would greatly enjoy discussing it in a different setting — a mailing list, a forum, or best of all perhaps over a beer at a conference.  I meant no criticism at all, beyond that I feel this is a bad fit for MO.  Anyhow, as you say, enough!

Comment: We know that it is consistent that ZFC is consistent but $\omega$-inconsistent (and arithmetically unsound.) Suppose that this is the case. Then, taking the $\mathbb{N}$ of the metatheory as the "absolute" natural numbers, we see that it is possible that none of the $\mathbb{N}$ of the models of ZFC are the "real" natural numbers.

Once you pull this formal argument "one layer back", we see that there is no way to argue that the set $\mathbb{N}$ of the metatheory, which is usually defined as the smallest inductive set in ZFC, is equal to the "real life" collection of numerals $0,S0,SS0,...$.

Comment: Therefore, I would say that you can (consistently) argue that there is little difference between $\mathbb{N}$ and $\mathbb{R}$ in this aspect. The idea that there is a "standard model" for arithmetic presupposes that the identification of the numerals 0,S0,SS0,... which are *strings in real life* (that is, terms of the metatheory) with the elements of the smallest inductive set, which are formal objects, is a bijection. However, this is just a huge leap of faith.

Comment: @Burak, thanks for this valuable input.  Would you care to format this as an *answer*?

Comment: @Timothy, I edited the *question* so as to address the concern you expressed with regard to V and R in [this comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/457042/standard-models-of-n-and-r-an-alice-bob-approach#comment1183792_457042).  I would therefore appreciate if you could delete this particular comment which is no longer necessary.

Comment: @MikhailKatz But that comment also contains my main answer to your question about what Kossak means. The software doesn't allow me to edit out a portion of an old comment. I could delete the entire comment and repost most of it, but then the chronological order of the comments would be messed up, making the thread of the conversation difficult to follow.

Comment: @FrançoisG.Dorais, since the existing answers [here](https://mathoverflow.net/a/458332/28128) and [here](https://mathoverflow.net/a/458387/28128) seem to disagree with your [*comment*](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/457042/standard-models-of-n-and-r-an-alice-bob-approach#comment1183841_457042), it may be helpful to expand the latter into an *answer*.

Comment: It is hard to pinpoint what question(s) is/are being asked.  Can the OP edit the post to make the question(s) more transparent?  This is just a respectful request.  I haven't read many of the other comments, because there are too many and usually in such case they are moved to discussion (at least in my experience).

Comment: @JesseElliott, Thanks for your *comment* and also your *answer* (so you must have figured out what the *question* was about).  At any rate, the question is formulated clearly above: Is there any difference between N and R on account of the question of the existence of a standard/intended model?

Comment: @MikhailKatz. Thanks for clarifying the question just now.  I just added a final paragraph in response.

Answer (score 11):

At the request of Mikhail, I am turning a comment of mine into a partial answer, even though what I am going to write down are well-known, presumably by Mikhail as well. While I am not going to directly argue for that there is little difference between $\mathbb{N}$ and $\mathbb{R}$ in terms of the plausibility of the existence of a standard/intended model, I shall argue that one cannot *argue against* this claim, at least not without strong (philosophical) assumptions regarding the underlying axiomatic system.

Since the metatheory-theory distinction matters in what follows, let me name a few things that I shall talk about. I shall work in ZFC whose language is augmented with a constant symbol $0$ for the empty set and a unary function symbol $S$ for the successor function. Let me introduce four different worlds.

- $\text{(R)}$ is the real physical world in which I write symbols on a paper and build my axiomatic system. The terms $0$, $S0$, $SS0$,... of my axiomatic system shall be referred to as **numerals**. Let me say that ZFC is *physically-consistent* if I can never derive a contradiction in my axiomatic system in the physical world we live in *even when we are provided with unlimited physical power, space and time*. Observe that this is not a mathematical statement in my axiomatic system, but rather is a statement about a physical phenomenon.
- $\text{(V)}$ is the set-theoretic world. In this world, the set $\mathbb{N}$ of natural numbers is defined to be the unique object $N$ for which the statement $$\varphi(N): 0 \in N \wedge \forall w (w \in N \rightarrow Sw \in N) \wedge (\forall x ((0 \in x \wedge \forall w (w \in x \rightarrow Sw \in x))\rightarrow (\forall w (w\in N \rightarrow w \in x)))$$ holds, i.e. it is the smallest inductive set. Observe that when I talk about a natural number $n \in \mathbb{N}$ in my axiomatic system, I only write statements that involve the variable symbol $n$. Therefore, when I talk about natural numbers, I do not necessarily talk about numerals; although, I can prove one by one that each numeral belongs to $\mathbb{N}$. Let me write $\text{Con(ZFC)}$ for the statement in my axiomatic system that formalizes the idea of physical-consistency that I had in mind. So $\text{Con(ZFC)}$ is a statement in my axiomatic system that is of the form $\forall n \in \mathbb{N} \dots$
- $\text{(M)}$ is a model of (various extensions) of $\text{ZFC}$. In this model, there is an object $\mathbb{N}^{\text{M}}$ which this model believes satisfies $\varphi$. This model has its own understanding of the statement $\text{Con(ZFC)}$ that is determined by $\mathbb{N}^{\text{M}}$.
- $\text{(M)}'$ is an object inside $\text{M}$ which $\text{M}$ thinks is a model of $\text{ZFC}$.

Here is my claim.

> **Philosophical claim.** There cannot be any methods to argue that the collection of numerals $0$, $S0$, $SS0$,... coincide with
> $\mathbb{N}$. In other words, we cannot argue that the numerals of
> $\text{R}$ and the natural numbers of $\text{V}$ are the same.

How can we argue for this claim? Since some of the objects to be discussed are not mathematical objects but rather physical strings of symbols in real life, surely we cannot argue for this claim mathematically as a theorem in our axiomatic system.

On the other hand, we can prove theorems *that will translate into* this once appropriately interpreted. By Gödel's theorem, we know that $$\text{Con(ZFC+Con(ZFC))} \rightarrow \text{Con(ZFC+Con(ZFC)}+\neg\text{Con(ZFC+Con(ZFC)))}$$
Hence, assuming that there is a model of $\text{ZFC+Con(ZFC)}$ at all, we can obtain a model $\text{M}$ of $$\text{ZFC+Con(ZFC)}+\neg\text{Con(ZFC+Con(ZFC))}$$
Inside this model, the formal statement $\text{Con(ZFC)}$ holds and so there are objects $\text{M}' \in \text{M}$ which $\text{M}$ thinks are models of $\text{ZFC}$. However, $\text{M}$ also believes $\neg\text{Con(ZFC+Con(ZFC))}$ and so believes that $\text{ZFC} \vdash \neg \text{Con(ZFC)}$. Therefore, the objects $\mathbb{N}^{\text{M}'}$ can never be equal to $\mathbb{N}^{\text{M}}$ from $\text{M}$'s perpective. That is, we can have *a model of set theory that thinks that all of the set models of $\text{ZFC}$ inside it are $\omega$-nonstandard from its perspective*.

Now let us *pull this argument back layer by layer*. $\text{M}'$ is to $\text{M}$ as $\text{M}$ is to $\text{V}$. Consequently, assuming that ZFC is physically-consistent and $\text{Con(ZFC)}$, we cannot prove that $\mathbb{N}$ and $\mathbb{N}^{\text{M}}$ are the same for an arbitrary set model $\text{M}$ of $\text{ZFC}$, not without additional assumptions, because all models of $\text{ZFC}$ may be $\omega$-nonstandard as simulated above.

In the same fashion, $\mathbb{N}^{\text{M}}$ is to $\mathbb{N}$ as $\mathbb{N}$ is to the collection of numerals. Therefore, we cannot hope to *even argue* that the collection of numerals and $\mathbb{N}$ are the same since any argument would have to break down somewhere once it is pushed back through these formal layers.

The idea that there is a standard/intended model of arithmetic presupposes that the formalization of the collection of numerals as the set $\mathbb{N}$ correctly captures the essence of the informal concept of numerals. Why should we believe in this?

Comment: :::Observe that this is not a mathematical statement in my axiomatic system, but rather is a statement about a physical phenomenon.::: This is an illusion. Suppose you make use of a computer programmed to search a contradiction in ZFC. Suppose after a zillion of years it produces the answer YES (there is a contradiction). How you may know for sure whether quantum-mechanical phenomena haven't corroborated the result?

Comment: @VladimirKanovei: I may not have understood your point. You mean what I call physical-consistency is subject to physical limitations and/or is a meaningless notion? My point is that, even if I provide you with all the unlimited physical space and time to recheck a computer's work, it is possible that, say, you prove the formal statement ~Con(ZFC) in ZFC whereas you, with all your unlimited physical power, won't be able to write down an actual proof of an inconsistency; so ZFC is formally inconsistent but not inconsistent "in reality" simply because its characterization of numerals is wrong.

Comment: Perhaps quicker to the punchline: Physical reality might be finite.  The V version of $\mathbb{N}$ would then not accurately model the physically real numerals.  (Or, the way I think about it: Physical reality might not model our intuitive notion of $\mathbb{N}$.)  Moreover, even if physical reality were infinite, its version of $\mathbb{N}$ could be a nonstandard model.  See https://mathoverflow.net/questions/332247/defining-the-standard-model-of-pa-so-that-a-space-alien-could-understand

Comment: @PaceNielsen, the business about "physical reality" is really a red herring here.  The main point is the distinction between metalanguage natural numbers and object-language (formal) natural numbers.  Arguably, the former correspond to a sorites-like subcollection of the latter.  So whether or not one assumes that the physical universe is finite, one can allow for the possibility that meta-language integers may not necessarily be finite.

Comment: @PaceNielsen, I should mention that on this view, the metalanguage integers are always "smaller" than the object-language integers.  Therefore they *cannot* be a nonstandard model of arithmetic.  Meanwhile, the object-language integers can always be nonstandard as per Hamkins' view (the set-theoretic multiverse perspective).

Comment: @MikhailKatz I (hopefully politely) disagree.  For me, metalanguage here can mean two different things; either (1) the *pre-mathematical* language that we use to communicate, or (2) another layer of formal language that models the type (1) language.  The actual pre-mathematical language of type (1) we use to communicate with each other exists in the physical world.  When we divorce ourselves from that connection, and think we have a firm conception of Platonic ideals, we run into the problem set theorists did with comprehension. (I agree with your post elsewhere: finite is hard to define.)

Comment: @PaceNielsen I think Mikhail Katz's point, as well as Vladimir Kanovei's point, is that the "physical world" directly contains things like ink and chalk and computer screens, but does not directly contain *symbols* or *derivations* or even *language*, which are abstract entities. Vibrating vocal cords and ink-covered pages have a direct physical existence, but *language* does not.

Comment: @TimothyChow I (again hopefully politely) disagree.  We can hypothesize that there is a Platonic ideal of "language", and try to treat it formally as an idea rather than an instantiation of marks and sounds.  But if someone were to say to me "I have a proof of Theorem X, but this physical universe is too limited to express it" I would say they don't have a proof (or they have access to something greater than the universe).  As for Vladimir Kanovei's point, we can only trust ourselves as far as we trust reality, since we are part of it. subject to the same rules.

Comment: @PaceNielsen I don't disagree with your most recent comment, but I think you are still missing what Katz and Kanovei are saying. Here's another way to put it. The elements of $\mathbb{N}$ are *numbers*, not *numerals*. You're entitled to believe that a *number* doesn't exist unless its corresponding *numeral* can be physically instantiated in the world, but that's an *additional* assumption over and above the theories we have about abstract objects such as numbers.

Comment: @Pace, I couldn't have put it better than Tim and besides, he is the professional logician.  The distinction between metalanguage and object-language is a standard one in logic, and I don't have the impression that the logicians think of the former in terms of physical representation.  ZFC is sometimes also used as the metalanguage.  Go represent *that* in physical reality!

Comment: @MikhailKatz: To make sure that what I called physical-consistency is not affected by our inability to execute certain tasks and physical limitations such as the (very likely possibility of the) universe being finite, I edited the answer and added the phrase "...even when we are provided with unlimited physical power, space and time" so that this addresses at least one of the issues that you and Pace were discussing about.

Comment: @MikhailKatz Perhaps we are talking past each other.  Let me try again, using ZFC as an example.  It is my understanding (and you can correct me if I'm wrong), that the object language of ZFC consists of variable symbols, logical connectives, a binary relation symbol $\in$, etc...  This object language was developed as a way to formalize what we do with actual marks on the page, when we do set theory.  The formal meta-language consists of whatever meta-concepts you take for granted. It is a formalization of those marks on the page we use to argue about the other marks we made about set theory.

Comment: But technically speaking, the formal object language and the formal meta-language are never instantiated abstractly, only in the real world, using marks on the page.  You've never seen a proof, except written down.  You've never had a truth of ZFC conveyed to you from someone else, without a physical medium relating it. Similarly, Turing machines (and other machines) were created to formalize the idea of a computation.  But we've never actually built a Turing machine.  Only finite machines, with finite tapes, that eventually break down.

Comment: Sure, it would be an extra assumption to assert that such machines are nonsensical without physical instantiation, **but** it is also an extra philosophical assumption to assert they *are* meaningful.  It is an act of faith (or, at least, agnosticism). So, to Timothy's point about the difference between a *number* and a *numeral*, the latter we have examples of, the former none.

Comment: Timothy's assertion that its "an *additional* assumption" that numbers don't exist unless they can be instantiated is true, but it is also true that it is an *additional* assumption that they are meaningful with no examples.  It is a *further* assumption to assert that there is a unique well-understood version of this abstract concept.  (And my post about super-Turing machines makes such a [philosophical] position extremely tenuous, in my opinion.)

Comment: As a final example demonstrating that these are extra philosophical assumptions, consider the case of the "comprehension" axiom of naive set theory.  People, for a long time, thought that their abstract conception of infinite collections was a "real" (or "consistent") thing.  In that case, it wasn't.  Even the idea that "consistency" is a meaningful concept, ultimately must be taken as a philosophical assumption, since we have no clear/unique conception of what finite means, hence no clear conception of what a finite proof means.

Comment: @PaceNielsen Why, on your view, do we assume that 1+1 always equals 2? Surely it equals 2 only most of the time?

Comment: @TimothyChow Mostly for the same reason that mathematicians assumed that naïve set theory was consistent until they found an inconsistency.  We make a leap of faith, based on our best guess.  If someone were to point out an inconsistency in Peano arithmetic, we would no longer be justified in such an assumption (since 1+1 would also sometimes equal 3). This would likely lead to us refine our idea of what addition means, etc...  (Not sure where you second question starting with "Surely" came from.)

Comment: @PaceNielsen Your "leap of faith" is precisely what Katz and Kanovei are talking about. To talk about axioms for numbers at all, one has to leap away from the physical world into the world of abstractions. If you insist on physics, then 1+1 will not exist (let alone equal 2) once your chosen numeral for 1 is physically large enough.

Comment: @TimothyChow I think you are misunderstanding my claims about physics if you think they say anything **against** taking leaps of faith to deal with abstractions.  If you agree with me that there are many different leaps of faith needed to assert the meaningfulness, "existence", and uniqueness of a standard model of PA, then you have understood my main point.

Comment: @PaceNielsen Again I don't dispute your most recent comment, but again I think you miss the point that Katz and Kanovei are making. We go ahead and assume that 1+1 is always 2 even though *we already know this assumption is physically false* for sufficiently large values of 1, as I remarked above. 1+1=2 does not accurately model physical numerals, but that doesn't faze us.

Comment: @TimothyChow For sake of argument, assume that we cannot write the numeral for $10^{10^{100}}$. Doesn't sound too bad.  Also, we can never run a computer that long, we can never write down proofs that long, we can never check for inconsistencies in PA whose length might be longer than that number.  That might not faze you or Katz or Kanovei, but it gives me a (little) pause.  It certainly makes me question what $\mathbb{N}$ is exactly.  Do I really know it exists?  Those pesky "..." in "0,1,2,..." take on more meaning.  Was the whole "completed vs. potential" infinity argument a waste of time?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/149746/discussion-between-timothy-chow-and-pace-nielsen).

Answer (score 9):

Like [Burak](https://mathoverflow.net/a/458332), I am responding to the OP's request to promote my comments to an answer, with the caveat that I want to avoid wading too deeply into philosophical debates that I think are beyond the scope of MO. I will try to focus on the question of what Kossak meant in the quoted paragraph. (The best authority on that topic is of course Kossak himself, but I think something can be said without asking him directly.)

The focus of the paragraph is the term "intended model of set theory" or "standard model of set theory." (Side remark: as [François G. Dorais commented](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/457042/standard-models-of-n-and-r-an-alice-bob-approach?noredirect=1#comment1183841_457042), "standard" in set theory typically means "well-founded," but I think that in this paragraph, "standard model of set theory" is being used as a synonym for "intended model of set theory." I will use the latter term to avoid confusion.) I maintain that "There is no intended model of set theory" is primarily intended here as a *sociological* claim, about mathematical practice. In particular, Kossak is *not* claiming that "There is no intended model of set theory" is a mathematical theorem. One can cite theorems that are relevant to the discussion, but the claim itself is not a formal mathematical claim.

Evidence for my claim can be found by looking around at how other people use the term "intended model of set theory." For example, Virginia Klenk's paper, [Intended models and the Löwenheim-Skolem theorem](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF02109439), makes it clear that she regards debates about the existence of an intended model of set theory as philosophical debates. In the (unpublished?) note, [Remarks on Intended Models of Mathematical Theories](https://web.archive.org/web/20210420055219/https://logic.amu.edu.pl/images/8/81/Intmod.pdf), Jerzy Pogonowski says, "We do not have
a *single intended model* of set theory ZF," but again in a way that makes it clear that it is not so much a mathematical theorem as a comment about the *practice* of set theory (e.g., the search for additional axioms for set theory).

To quote my own [comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/457042/standard-models-of-n-and-r-an-alice-bob-approach?noredirect=1#comment1183792_457042), people agree that the minimal model of first-order PA deserves to be called "the standard (or intended) model of the natural numbers." People don't agree that the minimal (transitive) model of ZFC, or any other specific model of ZFC, deserves to be called "the intended model of set theory." I don't think there's anything deeper than that going on in Kossak's paragraph. Now, whether people are *justified* in having different attitudes in the two cases is another matter, but as I said, that is a philosophical debate that I don't want to wade into here.

Comment: Thanks, Tim!  I think your sociological hypothesis is plausible (notice that I already included the tag [tag:sociology-of-math] :-) but, as I already mentioned in the *comments*, the *tone* of Kossak's comments has a more categorical ring about (here I obviously use "categorical" in its generic sense).  Thus, he writes: "The set of natural numbers N with addition and multiplication is called the standard
model of arithmetic" (not that "Logicians generally agree that the set of natural numbers, etc.").

Comment: To repeat my earlier comment, "called" is a sociological claim. But I agree that Kossak could be interpreted as not only reporting what others think, but signaling that he favors a particular side in a philosophical debate.

Comment: OK, but later on the same page one finds "In arithmetic, there is one
intended object of study – the standard model. There is no intended model in set
theory".  No "called" there.

Comment: @MikhailKatz If your main interest is in exactly what Roman Kossack meant in this article, you could try to contact them directly and ask them.

Comment: @Sam, I think we are past such preliminary comments on this *question*. It has had over 1000 views and the MO community is obviously interested in the issue, especially since 10 viewers have upvoted it. Kossak's paper is in the public domain and therefore any questions about it at MO are legitimate.

Answer (score 4):

I very much like Burak's and Timothy Chow's answers, and I hope that this answer complements theirs.  Your imaginary conversation between Alice and Bob got me thinking a little differently about your question: "Could one then argue that there is little diffence between N and R on account of the question of the existence of a standard/intended model?"  Particularly, I like how your question has used the word "intended".  To that end, please view this answer as an invitation to another Alice-and-Bob-like conversation.

When I think about what our formal systems of numbers are *intended* to model, I'd answer "the usual counting/arithmetic we do every day."  We have this picture in our heads of an idealized notion of number, which we (pre-mathematically) assume has a Platonically idealized existence in the world of concepts.  With the discovery that there are **multiple** models of the usual axioms that we (previously) thought should specify the numbers, and indeed with any computable list of axioms for said numbers, this throws a wrench in idea that we have a real picture of the Platonic ideal.  Then, as a saving grace, we learn that inside all of these models is a smallest one.  And of course, the picture in our head doesn't have any extraneous baggage thrown on top.  When we write $0,1,2,3,\cdots$, we don't think of those dots hiding the unnecessary, just the necessary.  This seems to save the day.

And yet, if one digs a bit deeper, problems seem to crop up again.  We discover that this intended model might not model "the usual counting/arithmetic we do every day" as intended, so we start having to make caveats.  We discover historical conversations about the difference between completed infinities and potential infinities.  Is a completed infinity the true model, or just a potentialist version?  The nearly universal acceptance of $\mathbb{N}$ seems to be more a matter of historical utility than of serious self-reflection.

I'd argue that all of that is somewhat irrelevant.  Any idea, when drilled down on, needs caveats, explanations, and our understanding has to expand and grow.  We went from believing the earth is flat, to being a sphere, to being an elongated ellipsoid.  None of those is perfectly accurate, but they are getting us further understanding at each stage.  Our understanding of the idealized numbers similarly continues to go through growth stages, which will necessitate a deeper understanding of what $\mathbb{N}$ is, but does not (for most of us) eliminate our hope that there is such an idealized notion.

The story is fundamentally different for ZFC.  Sets were originally *intended* to model **all** possible idealized collections.  The early paradoxes revealed that this idealized concept was inconsistent.  There is no entire collection.  There cannot be a "true" $V$.  There cannot even be a completed collection of all ordinals.

The intended model of the numbers is based on a minimality property; the smallest collection doing something.  The (original and naïve) intended model of sets is based on a maximality property; having the most freedom to talk about arbitrary collections.  This rules out wanting $V=L$ as an axiom, as that **limits** the types of collections available.

Comment: On is a proper class, as is V.  You seem to be advocating something like the pluralist or multiverse perspective.  I am a monist/pluralist dualist.  V = L doesn't limit what sets there are any more than the axiom of induction limits what natural numbers there are.  V = L says that On is very tall, not that V is very thin.  On is so tall, as it should be, that it doesn't matter how you take power sets, full or constructible: after you do so either way along all of the ordinals, you get the same result, viz., V.  By your argument, there is no reason to assume the axiom of foundation or even AC.

Comment: See https://arxiv.org/abs/1210.6541, for example.

Comment: @JesseElliott Many set theorists admit that the axiom of foundation is just an axiom of convenience for simplicity, limiting one's focus to the well-founded (hereditarily set-like) sets.  AC is something different.  It is similar to the axioms of union and power set, allowing one a power to construct new sets from old ones by pure assertion; and yet it is somewhat different in its impredicativity.  AC is like comprehension in that it asserts an ability to accomplish tasks in the realm of Platonic collections.

Comment: As for advocating pluralism, I'd say my position is a bit more nuanced than that.  The business with comprehension failing and On being an uncompleted infinity, lead me to believe (on the level of mathematical abstraction) that set theory is inherently limited to certain contexts (or types, if you will).  So, yes, there are many possible universes, for the many possible types of sets.

Comment: OK, then can you describe one type of set that there is precisely?

Comment: AC forces the reals to be well-orderable.  Why not allow for a vision of the reals as non-wellorderable?   Why not allow for vector spaces with no basis?  Etc.  I don't see your point about AC.  It, too, limits what sets there can be.

Comment: @JesseElliott Good questions.  Now change AC to the axiom of unions  Why not allow a collection of collections where it has no union?  Answer that question, and then translate back to AC.  (My answer is: We accept the axiom of union, because we are familiar with unions in the context of finite sets, and we imagine it should similarly work for any collection of sets.  Likewise, we accept AC, because we are familiar with fixing elements from finitely many nonempty sets, and we imagine it should work for any collection.  Yes, both of these axioms limit the types of collections available.)

Comment: Now, likewise apply it to the axiom of powerset, without which we wouldn't even have the reals...

Comment: "With the discovery that there are multiple models of the usual axioms that we (previously) thought should specify the numbers" This is historically inaccurate. I don't think anybody ever expected *first-order* Peano arithmetic to be categorical.

Comment: @TimothyChow I did.  I know many others who were flabbergasted that there are these nonstandard models.  But, if you were never surprised by this fact during your education, you can certainly modify my "we" to "many of us".  (In hindsight, I see how naïve it was to have this belief.  And yet, it is a common one among the uneducated.  And it isn't so surprising since there are no computable nonstandard models.)

Comment: @PaceNielsen In my own education, I went through a period where I was confused about the difference between first-order arithmetic and second-order arithmetic. I'm sure many others experience this confusion, because it isn't always explained well in pedagogical texts. But it strikes me as misleading to portray a common student misconception as something that took the mathematical community by surprise. Many students are surprised when they first learn that there is more than one mathematical object that satisfies the axioms for a commutative ring, but I wouldn't call this a "discovery."

Comment: Reread my post, with "we" not understood as an abstract "mathematical community", but with "we" read as "you and me and others reading along".  (Anyway, we can agree to disagree whether learning mathematics for ourselves is a process of discovery.)

Answer (score 2):

This is way too long for a remark, therefore I post it as an answer.

Although I agree with the previous answers that there is probably no clear “intended” model of set theory, there are perhaps two principles for any “standard” model of set theory which many mathematicians could agree upon, though I am not sure how to formalize them. However, in contrast to the claim in the original question, I do not think that this is some general sort of “maximality” principle, but partially quite the opposite. To formulate the principles at least intuitively, let me first point out that set theory knows (at least) about two set hierarchies:

1. The hierarchy of ordinals.
2. The hierarchy of power sets.

Since there seems to be an agreement that the “standard“ model of $\mathbb N$ should be guided by some “minimality” principle, one should probably assume for a standard model of set theory as well that the set-theoretic analogue $\omega_0$ should correspond to such a “standard” model of $\mathbb N$. More general, it seems to me that many mathematicians could agree that the whole hierarchy of ordinals which reflect “infinite counting“ should obey such a form of “minimality” principle for a “standard” model. I think that this means, roughly speaking, that the considered models of set theory should not “skip” any ordinals which might exist in “smaller” models. (As mentioned, I am not sure whether or how this could be formalized; at least 1st order logic does not seem to be sufficient for this.)

For the hierarchy of power sets, with $\mathbb R$ and its power set being the “simplest“ examples in the infinite case, however, many mathematicians could perhaps agree indeed on some sort of “maximal comprehension” principle in the sense that the model should not have an artificial restriction on the “admissible” subsets: Anything which forms a “collection“ of elements of a set $M$ in any intuitive sense should be a set of the model. In particular, also non-constructible sets (opposing V=L) and “exotic“ sets (like non-measurable or non-Baire subsets of $\mathbb R$ or non-principal ultrafilters on $\mathbb N$) should be sets of the model, probably even many sets which (in contrast to the known constructions of “exotic” sets based on AC) cannot be obtained with AC alone. Such a “maximal comprehension” principle, of course, is even harder to formalize (if at all possible) than the minimality principle for ordinals (and very likely not possible at all to formalize in 1st order logic).

Side notes:

- In physics, apparently no “exotic” sets do exist. Therefore, if one uses set theory to “model“ in a physical sense some real-world problem, it might be more natural to consider a model without such exotic sets even at the cost of the full power of AC. That's why some applied mathematicians might consider the “maximal comprehension” principle above questionable.
- The axiomatic approaches to NSA (for instance of Nelson) mentioned in the original question violate both principles “formulated” above: Neither does ”their” $\omega_0$ obey some minimality principle, nor does the natural collection of standard elements of any (infinite) set $M$ of the model form a set in the sense of the model.

Comment: Consider the collection of metalanguage integers.   According to your claim, one would have to either view it as somehow "unnatural", or reconcile oneself to the idea that "maximal comprehension" is currently an unattainable ideal :-)  Note that Nelson's IST does not "miss" any small ordinals, and in particular $\omega_0$ has exactly the same meaning as in ZFC (which is a subtheory of IST).

Comment: I stand to the (admissibly sloppy) claim that any model of IST "misses" the "standard copy" $\omega_0$, that is, the collection of those elements of $\omega_0$ which are standard. Yes, this is not a set in the IST language, but this is exactly what I mean by the sloppy formulation that IST "misses" it. And I do not agree that $\omega_0$ has the same meaning as in ZFC, since most models of ZFC (in which $\omega_0$ is minimal) cannot be extended to a model of IST: You just cannot see the difference from inside the model which is something else than being the "same".

Comment: This is a shortcoming of IST that has  certainly been taken note of by specialists like Hrbacek and Kanovei.  That's why BST is the preferred axiom system for nonstandard analysis.  As far as BST is concerned, all models of ZFC do extend.  BST has a number of other advantages.  Note that SPOT is a subtheory of IST, but SCOT is not.  Meanwhile, both SPOT and SCOT are subtheories of BST.  As far as $\omega_0$ is concerned, it has exactly the same technical meaning in ZFC and in BST (also IST).  Saying that axiomatic NSA somehow "misses" $\omega_0$ is missing the point of axiomatic NSA.

Comment: Concerning the collection of metalanguage integers and maximal comprehension: If I understand Jessie Elliott's comment correctly, it might be possible to formalize at least this special case in higher order logic. But even if it is not possible to formalize this special case or the general case, at least it can help to *exclude* some models (like IST) from having this property. Whether there actually *are* models with this property is probably hard to prove, though intuitively plausible (as I believe that this is what many mathematicians visualize when they think about sets).

Comment: Martin, I am not a specialist but I believe there is a consensus among a majority of set theorists *against* assuming $V=L$.  I certainly wouldn't presume to present an opinion, but on this score Elliott's idea seems to be overruled.  I would venture the following opinion, however: I don't see how anyone could formalize metalanguage integers.  Admittedly, I am influenced by [Reeb](https://mathoverflow.net/q/231599/28128)  :-)

Comment: "There is a consensus among a majority of set theorists against assuming V=L". I did not mean this part of Elliott's reply (V=L clearly contradicts "maximal comprehension"): I meant the first part  of the explanation, how non-standard natural numbers are ruled out by higher order logic. I assume that the same idea can be used for sets to make sure that $\omega_0$ is standard.

Comment: "Saying that axiomatic NSA somehow "misses" $\omega_0$ is missing the point of axiomatic NSA.". That's a misunderstanding: I claimed that NSA "misses" the "standard copy" of $\omega_0$ ("standard copy" what it would be in Robinson's approach). Of course, there is some nonstandard entity $\omega_0$ in IST, but this is much larger - actually *must* be much larger, because it *must* contain nonstandard elements.

Comment: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/331956/why-not-adopt-the-constructibility-axiom-v-l

Comment: @Reeb.  No, there isn't a consensus.  For example, read https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/BFb0070208

Comment: Martin, I am told the following.  You seem to call for a universe with
“minimal” ordinals and “maximal" power sets.  However, these issues
are connected.  For example, Donald [Martin’s
Maximum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Martin%27s_maximum), a strong
“maximal” principle, implies the existence of subuniverses with large
cardinals, i.e., it is not compatible with “minimal” ordinals.  I hope
some experts in the field chime in on this.

Comment: "large cardinals ... is not compatible with “minimal” ordinals.". This is not what I mean by minimality principle for ordinals. Instead I mean by it: In the same way as there are no “nonstandard” natural numbers in the "standard" $\mathbb N\cong\omega_0$, there should also be no “nonstandard” ordinals in any other limit ordinal in a "standard" model, so that all must be “standard” in a sense. I have no strong intuition whether or not this allows large cardinals, but I guess that this is independent.

Comment: I do not really understand forcing, so I also do not understand whether "Martin's Maximum" has anything to do with what I called "maximal comprehension".

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to pinpoint what question is being asked in this post, but here is my attempt at an answer.

Second-order number theory with full semantics pinpoints the intended model of the structure of natural numbers.  First-order PA does not.  Second-order induction, or the first-order approximation as an induction schema, attempt to pinpoint what "numbers" there aren't, i.e., to rule out nonstandard models.

ZF+$V=L$ quite effectively says what sets there aren't, in order to limit models of ZFC.  It quite naturally implies AC, as well as the GCH.  To me, it doesn't say that V is "skinny", rather, it says that On is "tall".  There is no reason to reject V=L in favor of measurable cardinals and other "very large" cardinals, just like there is no reason to reject AC in favor of Reinhardt cardinals.  Large cardinals are metamathematical objects, as are models of ZF in which AC is false.

Edit: I think the undue resistance to the axiom of constructibility stalemates any reasonable attempts at nailing down a unique category of sets. I don't believe "ultimate L" will ever gain popular traction, for reasons that should be apparent.

Regarding large cardinals: I have never seen them used in ring theory or number theory (my two main passions), and I see them fundamentally as metamathematical tools for gauging the consistency strengths of various theories.  I would be probably ok with ruling out worldly cardinals and above, but I don't think of such objects enough to advocate banishing them or alternatively demanding that they must exist.  I think the question of whether $V$ equals $L$ is far more important to settle.

My opinion about $V=L$ is in the minority, but it has had some important supporters.

Aside regarding Edward Nelson's $\mathbb{N}$ alluded to in the OP: I am a huge fan of that version of nonstandard analysis.  Introducing a new predicate "standard" is an elegant way of doing infinitesimals in a conservative extension of PA. I actually prefer Nelson's elementary nonstandard analysis to standard calculus.  Infinitesimals are often more easily grasped than $\epsilon$-$\delta$ limits are, e.g., by physicists. I hope that in 100 years we will be back to using infinitesimals in calculus.

Finally, regarding the question, is there a difference between $\mathbb{N}$ and $\mathbb{R}$ with regard to standard models, etc?  My position is that there is a unique initial object (namely, $\mathbb{N}$) in the category of semirings with identity, and a unique terminal object (namely, $\mathbb{R}$) in the category of archimedean ordered fields, up to isomorphism, and these categories themselves are unique in the meta-category of categories, and that questions of standard models, etc., are metamathematical concerns having to do with limitations of first-order logic and formal systems.  This is a "monist Platonist" stance.  At the same time, I recognize the value of considering nonstandard models of arithmetic and analysis, or of sets where $V$ is not $L$, or where even AC and the axiom of foundation both fail. If $V = L$ is eventually accepted, as I hope it will be, then that will settle CH and GCH in the positive and thus afford us a more complete picture of the true $\mathbb{R}$.

Here are a few of many references I could provide.

https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/BFb0070208 (Keith Devlin, The Axiom of Constructibility: A Guide for the Mathematician)

https://arxiv.org/abs/1210.6541 (Joel David Hamkins: A multiverse perspective on the axiom of constructiblity)

[Why not adopt the constructibility axiom $V=L$?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/331956/why-not-adopt-the-constructibility-axiom-v-l) (MO question from 2019)

Comment: I expected a different direction after your second paragraph; we can [make](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1213020/why-isnt-second-order-zfc-categorical#:~:text=Second%2Dorder%20ZFC,is%20isomorphic%20to%20Vk.) ZFC categorical by tweaking the axiom of infinity, so is this really where your contention lies?

Comment: To elaborate on @AlecRhea's comment, second-order ZF + "there is no inaccessible cardinal" is categorical in the context of ZF + "there is an inaccessible cardinal."

Comment: I am a proponent of second-order number theory, but not necessarily of second-order set theory or of the insistence that even worldly cardinals exist or do not exist.  ZF+V=L is silent on various "not very large cardinals".

Comment: I have never needed to use large cardinals in my research.  I gather that they are primarily a metamathematical tool for guaging consistency strengths of various theories.  ZF+V=L is equiconsistent with ZFC.  ZFC+Inaccessibles is not.

Comment: Moreover, I think the undue resistance to the axiom of constructibility stalemates any reasonable attempts at nailing down a unique category of sets.

Comment: I've edited my response in light of this.  Thank you for the comments!

Comment: You wrote: "Introducing a new predicate *standard* is an elegant way of doing infinitesimals in a conservative extension of PA" :  I am not sure what you mean.  Nelson's framework is not conservative over PA.  It is conservative over ZFC.  Some recent theories in this vein are conservative over ZF, but at any rate not over PA.

Comment: Also, your "aside" about Nelson does not address the point I was making with regard to "the" standard model of N: Nelson's N is also "the" well-founded model in precisely the same technical sense mentioned by Dorais, but I think you will agree with me that Dorais' N does not look the "same" as Nelson's.

Comment: Jesse, for a non-artificial connection between large cardinals and number theory, there is the conjecture that the first row of a Laver table has unbounded period.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laver_table

Comment: Regarding accepting V=L, the MO question https://mathoverflow.net/questions/331956/why-not-adopt-the-constructibility-axiom-v-l raises that very question, and has some interesting answers.  However, if you can persuade mathematicians that the only *true* operations mathematicians will ever have access to---in both deed and thought---are the Godelian operations, then you might make headway in getting V=L accepted.  However, do you truly believe that the Godelian operations are really all that one can do with infinite collections?

Comment: What are some other operations on infinite collections that you would like to advocate?

Comment: Rank-to-rank are "essentially the strongest known large cardinal axioms not known to be inconsistent in ZFC; the axiom for Reinhardt cardinals is stronger, but is not consistent with the axiom of choice."  Thus, I advocate not using them.  Mathematicians are interested in axioms with low consistency strength, not high, as set theorists want us to accept.  The higher the consistency strength, the more likely there's an inconsistency.

Comment: Also, one can combine Godelian operations transfinitely, so saying that they are the only operations is misleading.  Which operations would you like to add to Godel's collection?

Comment: "Which operations would you like to add to Godel's collection?"  Personally, none right now.  But philosophically, I have no reason to think that transfinite combinations of them yield every conceivable operation on collections.  That said, others *have* put forward lots of options!  Really, take any property you can do with finite sets, generalize to an operation on infinite sets, and see what happens.  What makes union and powerset so special that they get to work for infinite collections, but others don't?  Finite sets are measurable, why shouldn't all collections be measurable?

Comment: L is a minimal model with a universal property, and so monism dictates that V must equal L, much like second-order number theory outlaws nonstandard models of arithmetic.  Which large cardinals are you in favor of or not in favor of?

Comment: "L is a minimal model with a universal property, and so monism dictates that V must equal L..."  It does not minimally model ZFC-Union.  Nor of ZFC-Infinity.  To argue that L is a minimal model, you need to first have accepted a list of axioms.  That occurs before you can appeal to monism.

Comment: @JesseElliott When you say that large cardinals are primarily a metamathematical tool, are you just saying that this is the current state of the art, or do you think it is a permanent state of affairs? In particular, do you not expect extensions of [Harvey Friedman's results](https://mathoverflow.net/q/129575/) to ever have any impact on "mainstream" number theory?

Comment: @TimothyChow.  I cannot make such a prediction.  Maybe it will get to that point someday.  For now, I see the Whitehead problem, determining the global dimension of $\prod_{n = 1}^\infty \mathbb{F}_2$, resolving the cardinals in Cinchon's diagram, etc., as far more crucial.  Second-order number theory can handle Goodstein's theorem, etc., and I'm not aware of any "big" and "natural" problems in number theory as, say, the Whitehead problem is in algebra.  I find many of the combinatorial problems to be contrived.

Comment: @PaceNielsen.  Assume KP, and then KP+V=L.

Comment: @JesseElliott I have some sympathy for V=L, but I don't think it is likely to be "eventually accepted." This is mainly because I don't think anything beyond ZFC is ever going to be accepted as foundational (except possibly infinitely many inaccessibles, which some proof assistants already assume). But also, to put it somewhat bluntly, "accepting" V=L amounts to saying that set theory isn't math, and I can't see set theorists ever going along with that view. Some "mainstream" mathematicians might happily say that set theory isn't math, but they probably don't care about V=L either.

Comment: @TimothyChow I disagree (in 200+ pages, currently) vehemently.   Saying that V is not equal to L is saying that set theory isn't math.  We can agree that set-theoretic universes in which AC (or foundation, or other axioms of ZFC) is false are important, and we can probably agree that insisting that AC is true, notwithstanding, but not necessarily true in every interesting model of ZF, isn't insisting that set theory isn't math in any way, shape, or form.  Why is V = L any different than AC (which rules out Reinhardt cardinals)?  In 100 years, I hope V = L will be accepted.

Comment: Large cardinals and the bulk of modern set theory are more metamathematics than mathematics.  Most mathematicians probably can't even list all of the axioms and axiom schemas of ZFC.  Even at Berkeley, where I did my PhD in math, set theory isn't offered to math grad students, and the departments are separate (Math v Logic and Methodology of Science).  We arguably speak different languages.  What is your opinion about V = "ultimate L"?

Comment: @TimothyChow  V = L is very simple to understand and is expressible in KP, a very weak fragment of ZFC.  Have you read Keith Devlin's The Axiom of Constructibility: A Guide for the Mathematician?  I read it cover to cover in like three days.  There he gives a thorough treatment of V = L and some compelling arguments in its favor.  He and I are not alone in our support of V = L. Try giving a Hugh Woodin paper a read, on the other hand.  Not so easy.  V = L is easy to understand and easy to motivate.  Much easier than understanding forcing or multiverse theory,

Comment: @TimothyChow. In addition to the follow-up questions I posed to you, what is your opinion about whether CH and/or GCH will eventually be accepted or rejected?

Comment: @JesseElliott Devlin's book is great and as I said, I have some sympathy for V=L. When I first learned about how it settled so many questions, I was puzzled why it was not more widely accepted. But I came to realize that *accepting* it (as opposed to treating it as an "optional" axiom, like $0^\sharp$ or $\diamond$) is regarded as a declaration that (e.g.) measurable cardinals aren't real, thereby marginalizing vast swaths of set theory. AC and Foundation are no different in this sense; accepting them means marginalizing Reinhardt cardinals and well-founded sets.

Comment: To put it another way, why not just be happy that V=L is available for anyone who wants to assume it? Why push for it to be *foundational*? The only reason I can see is a desire to downgrade the status of set-theoretical assumptions that contradict it. It's a political move, and hence will be opposed for political reasons. As for V = "ultimate L", the same sort of comments apply, and on top of that I agree with you that it's basically incomprehensible to most mathematicians, which is an obvious additional barrier. And finally, I don't think (G)CH will be either accepted or rejected.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/149963/discussion-between-timothy-chow-and-jesse-elliott).